# Druid segments not available

Tags: druid

[image]
Hi Guys, There are ingestion tasks going on in my druid server setup on Kubernetes. Lot of segments in multiple datasources are not available, even though ingestion was successful. As a result I am not able to show the ingested data in my app. Why are segments unavailable and how to rectify it? Also what are the steps to restart all druid components setup on multi node Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say why segments are unavailable without looking at some logs. The coordinator log and the historical logs will be useful to determine why historical processes are unable to make the segments available (download them from deep storage).
A quick thought, could you be out of space for the historicals segment-cache ?